# react-sortablejs - sorting between dynamic groups

Tags: reactjs

I am using https://github.com/SortableJS/react-sortablejs
Hello my question is that how to handle **react sortablejs** when using nested data structure.
I want a group in which there are items which will be sortable and there will be many group and they share items on each group.

I am able to create sort within one group but can't update state on group to group drag dropping...

I am getting order instead of object in  `onChange={(items) => {` when you use ['apple', 'orange'] it will easily work but when you use object then item will return [object Object].

Can anyone help me.

groupsortable.js

```
import uniqueId from 'lodash/uniqueId';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Sortable from 'react-sortablejs';
import SharedGroup from './shared-group';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import _ from 'lodash'
import './App.css';

class GroupSortable extends React.Component {
    state = {
        sharedGroupArray: [
            {
                gname: 'Group 1',
                gid: '1',
                data: [
                    {
                        id: '1',
                        name: 'prashen'
                    },
                    {
                        id: '2',
                        name: 'sumit'
                    },
                    {
                        id: '3',
                        name: 'sam'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                gname: 'Group 2',
                gid: '2',
                data: [
                    {
                        id: '4',
                        name: 'avinash'
                    },
                    {
                        id: '5',
                        name: 'nikunj'
                    },
                    {
                        id: '6',
                        name: 'ravi'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                gname: 'Group3',
                gid: '3',
                data: [
                    {
                        id: '7',
                        name: 'priyank'
                    },
                    {
                        id: '8',
                        name: 'preeti'
                    },
                    {
                        id: '9',
                        name: 'ujval'
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    };

    /**
     * making it in order
     */
    mapOrder = (array, order, key) => {

        array.sort(function (a, b) {
            var A = a[key], B = b[key];

            if (order.indexOf(A) > order.indexOf(B)) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }

        });

        return array;
    };


    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.sharedGroupArray.map((i, gind) => {

                    return <SharedGroup
                        key={gind}
                        className="groups"
                        items={i.data}
                        options={{
                            animation: 150,
                            group: {
                                name: 'shared',
                                pull: true,
                                put: true
                            },
                        }}

                        onChange={(items) => {
                            let returnedObj;
                            let orderedReturnArray
                            items.filter((fi, fInd) => {

                                if (i.data[gind].id === fi) {
                                    i.data;
                                    orderedReturnArray = this.mapOrder(i.data, items, 'id')

                                    return orderedReturnArray
                                }
                            })

                            let updateData = [...this.state.sharedGroupArray];

                            updateData[gind].data = orderedReturnArray;

                            this.setState({ sharedGroupArray: updateData });
                        }}
                    />
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default GroupSortable;
```

sharegroup.js

```
 import uniqueId from 'lodash/uniqueId';
import React from 'react';
import Sortable from 'react-sortablejs';

// Functional Component
const SharedGroup = ({ items, ...props }) => {
    // console.log(items)
    items = items.map(val => (<div key={uniqueId()} data-id={val.id}>{val.name}</div>));

    return (
        <Sortable
            // See all Sortable options at https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable#options

            tag="div"
            {...props}
        >
            {items}
        </Sortable>
    );
};

export default SharedGroup;
```